# React Three JS not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I've been trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRmeFtRkF-8

but when I run my code, I only get a blank (black - background color set in the CSS) canvas. I know the canvas is operational because when I scroll on the black portion, I do not scroll up and down the page. I used the same code in the video / github and only replaced react-three-fiber with @react-three/fiber.

Here is my code:

```
import './Ripple.css';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { Canvas, extend, useFrame, useLoader, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';
import circleImg from './assets/circle.png';
import { Suspense, useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';
extend({OrbitControls})

function CameraControls(){
  const {
    camera,
    gl: {domElement}
  } = useThree();

  const controlsRef = useRef();
  useFrame(() => controlsRef.current.update())

  return (
    <orbitControls
      ref={controlsRef}
      args={[camera, domElement]}
      autoRotate
      autoRotateSpeed={-0.2}
    />
  );
}

function Points() {
  const imgTex = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, circleImg);
  const bufferRef = useRef();

  let t = 0;
  let f = 0.002;
  let a = 3;
  const graph = useCallback((x, z) => {
    return Math.sin(f * (x ** 2 + z ** 2 + t)) * a;
  }, [t, f, a])

  const count = 100
  const sep = 3
  let positions = useMemo(() => {
    let positions = []

    for (let xi = 0; xi < count; xi++) {
      for (let zi = 0; zi < count; zi++) {
        let x = sep * (xi - count / 2);
        let z = sep * (zi - count / 2);
        let y = graph(x, z);
        positions.push(x, y, z);
      }
    }

    return new Float32Array(positions);
  }, [count, sep, graph])

  useFrame(() => {
    t += 15
    
    const positions = bufferRef.current.array;

    let i = 0;
    for (let xi = 0; xi < count; xi++) {
      for (let zi = 0; zi < count; zi++) {
        let x = sep * (xi - count / 2);
        let z = sep * (zi - count / 2);

        positions[i + 1] = graph(x, z);
        i += 3;
      }
    }

    bufferRef.current.needsUpdate = true;
  })

  return (
    <points>
      <bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
        <bufferAttribute
          ref={bufferRef}
          attachObject={['attributes', 'position']}
          array={positions}
          count={positions.length / 3}
          itemSize={3}
        />
      </bufferGeometry>

      <pointsMaterial
        attach="material"
        map={imgTex}
        color={0x00AAFF}
        size={0.5}
        sizeAttenuation
        transparent={false}
        alphaTest={0.5}
        opacity={1.0}
      />
    </points>
  );
}

function AnimationCanvas() {
  return (
    <Canvas
      colorManagement={false}
      camera={{ position: [100, 10, 0], fov: 75 }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Points />
      </Suspense>
      <CameraControls/>
    </Canvas>
  );
}


function Ripple() {
  return (
    <div className="anim">
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <AnimationCanvas />
        </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Ripple;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have any errors in your developer console?

Comment: @LeeTaylor  

I have one warning: DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://kjacjjdnoddnpbbcjilcajfhhbdhkpgk/content.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

and one error:


```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: React does not recognize the `colorManagement` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `colormanagement` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    at div
    at Canvas
    ...
```

Comment: Does the problem go away if you temporarily remove that line, or otherwise use lowercase?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I removed the line and the error goes away but the code does not work. If I change it to lower case, I get another error to change the boolean value to a string. I did that and there are no more errors, just the warning I mentioned in the prior comment

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by using PresentationControls and Stage instead of OrbitalControls, here's a working snippet

```
<Canvas
  camera={{ position: [2, 0, 12.25], fov: 15 }}
  style={{
    backgroundColor: '#111a21',
    width: '100vw',
    height: '100vh',
  }}
>
  <PresentationControls >
    <ambientLight intensity={1.25} />
    <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
    <directionalLight intensity={0.4} />
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <Stage>
        <Model />
      </Stage>
    </Suspense>

  </PresentationControls>
</Canvas>
```